# JQueryUI dialog not working in my laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-ui

In My view file I am importing my necessary libraries as following

```
{{ Html::script(asset('js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js')) }}
{{ Html::script(asset('js/jquery-ui.min.js')) }}
{{ Html::style(asset('css/jquery-ui.css')) }}
```

Then I have the following in my view to create dialog:

```
<button id="hello">Click Me</button>
 <div id="dialog1" style="display:none">
    <div>
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

And just at the bottom I have the following Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
});

$("#hello").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
});
```

The same thing is working in jsfiddle but not in my laravel. Do i need to do anything? I am getting the the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Here is how my files are loaded

```
    @extends('layouts.headerfooter')
@section('content')
    {{ Html::style(asset('css/home.css')) }}
    {{ Html::script(asset('js/home.js')) }}
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"   integrity="sha256-VuhDpmsr9xiKwvTIHfYWCIQ84US9WqZsLfR4P7qF6O8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {{Html::script('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js')}}
    {{ Html::script('js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}
    {{ Html::style('css/jquery-ui.css') }}
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
});

$("#hello").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
});
</script>
<div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Is your script triggered *after* the JS files are loaded? Are the JS files accessible? Sounds like one of those 2 things is going on.

Comment: js files are accessible I am sure about that. But how to check whether triggering is done after js files are loaded?

Comment: Well, tell us where in the DOM are your JS documents and where is your script located. Or, inspect the DOM yourself.

Comment: My JS documents are just above bellow the body tag.

Comment: And I have placed my scripts in a separate folder. I am loading those after the body tag and also in between the head tag. None is working

Comment: So are your custom scripts loaded after the jQuery files? That is how it should be.

Comment: Have you checked the URLs being generated by your helpers are correct?

Comment: Custom scripts are loaded after jquery. Yes urls are correct.

Answer (score 1):

it might be that your jquery-ui is customize and doesnt include dialog widget, try also putting your

`$("#hello").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
});`

inside the `$(document).ready(...)`